# Adding text via jQuery in IE11 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Adding text to a DOM element via jQuery using Internet Explorer 11 is not working.  Seems to work fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Here is the example:

```
<span id="derp"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#derp").text("here is the text");
</script>
```

When I display the page in IE11 it shows only **[object Object]**.

I have also tried using JQuery's `.html()` method within the script with same effect.  Any ideas?

Comment: That should work just fine, and with the given code it's hard to say why it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle with full html/js

Comment: Ok, one moment guys, I´ll do that and post it here.  Thanx :)

Comment: Is the js code in a document ready or similar?  Could IE be running itbefore jQuery has loaded?  As @adeneo said, the code looks fine...

Comment: hmmm, you guys are correct.  The problem is probably lying elsewhere, I used jsFiddle and it worked fine.  I have to review my code again, I´ll post it here when I have hit the bug.  Thank you guys.

Comment: Hi again guys, I´ve found the problem with my code.  Earlier in my code I was fecthing text from the markup to display elsewhere (like with my query above), and found out that IE is fetching that particular data diferently.  After sorting that out I found a way to get this to work.  I´ve upped your comments, but I´m afraid this was my bad, I should have done more reasearch before asking question here on StackOverflow.  Thank you guys again :)

Answer (score 0):

Check other browser to clarify problem, whether it is about Internet Explorer or not.

Then check where you load jquery.js in your HTML file.

Use firebug or other javascript console adapted with web browser to indentify from which lineof your code problems come from.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not an answer, it should be posted as a comment, and by posting a few more *real* answers you'll get upvotes so you can post comments and do other stuff. Also, make sure you read the question, the OP is stating that it works in other browsers, just not in IE11, and there's no way to use Firebug to check for errors that only occur in IE11 ?

Comment: Sorry, there are some mistakes understanding question.